# Objective-C Blocks with closure that references the host object

Tags: objective-c, closures, objective-c-blocks, host-object

I've been playing with blocks and encountered a weird behavior.
This is the interface/implementation, which just holds a block with the ability to execute it:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject {
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
    void (^blk)(void);
#endif
}
- (id)initWithBlock:(void (^)(void))block;
- (void)exec;
@end

@implementation TestClass
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
- (id)initWithBlock:(void (^)(void))block {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        blk = Block_copy(block);
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)exec {
    if (blk) blk();
}
- (void)dealloc {
    Block_release(blk);
    [super dealloc];
}
#endif
@end
```

While a regular instantiation and passing a regular block works:

```
TestClass *test = [[TestClass alloc] initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass");
}];
[test exec];
[test release];
```

Using a block with reference to the object which is being created doesn't:

```
TestClass *test1 = [[TestClass alloc] initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass %@", test1);
}];
[test1 exec];
[test1 release];
```

Error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS, stack trace on Block_copy(block);
Debugger on: 0x000023b2  <+0050>  add    $0x18,%esp

I kept playing around, and moved the allocation code above the initialization, it worked:

```
TestClass *test2 = [TestClass alloc];
test2 = [test2 initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass %@", test2);
}];
[test2 exec];
[test2 release];
```

And combining both snippets works too:

```
TestClass *test1 = [[TestClass alloc] initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass %@", test1);
}];
[test1 exec];
[test1 release];

TestClass *test2 = [TestClass alloc];
test2 = [test2 initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass %@", test2);
}];
[test2 exec];
[test2 release];
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an assignment expression, the rvalue is evaluated before being assigned to the lvalue.

This means that in:

```
TestClass *test1 = [[TestClass alloc] initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass %@", test1);
}];
```

the following sequence of operations is performed. **Edit:** as pointed out by Jonathan Grynspan, there’s no defined order for steps 1 and 2 so it could be the case that step 2 is executed before step 1.

1. Send `+alloc` to `TestClass`
2. Create a block that refers to `test1`, which hasn’t been initialised yet. `test1` contains an arbitrary memory address.
3. Send `-initWithBlock:` to the object created in step 1.
4. Assign the rvalue to `test1`.

Note that `test1` points to a valid object only after step 4.

In:

```
TestClass *test2 = [TestClass alloc];
test2 = [test2 initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass %@", test2);
}];
[test2 exec];
[test2 release];
```

the sequence is:

1. Send `+alloc` to `TestClass`
2. Assign the rvalue to `test2`, which now points to a `TestClass` object.
3. Create a block that refers to `test2`, which points to the `TestClass` object per step 2.
4. Send `-initWithBlock:` to `test2`, which was correctly assigned in step 2.
5. Assign the rvalue to `test2`.

Comment: Actually, the order of evaluation between `[TestClass alloc]` and `^{ ... }` is undefined. At the C level, both are evaluated as arguments to `-initWithBlock:`, so the block could actually be created *before* `[TestClass alloc]` is called. :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, this is why I tried to split the statements. But how come it works when both non-working snippet and working snippet are combined?

Comment: @elado It doesn’t, at least not reliably. It depends on what `test1` contains before the assignment, which is undefined.

Comment: @elado Also, you’re not returning `self` in your `-init…` method.

Comment: @Bavarious I fixed the return self. It did fix the odd situation where the two snippets were running ok. The mystery on the EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the closure before alloc is solved. Thank you guys!

Comment: It's also worth noting that in the second case, it only "works" in this particular case because `-[TestClass initWithBlock:]` returns the object it is called on. But initializers are not guaranteed to return the object it is called on; they can return `nil` or another object (in the latter case they would release the object they were called on, and retain the one they return). If `-[TestClass initWithBlock:]` had returned a different object, then the same problem as the first case would occur.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when a block is created, it will copy (make a separate copy) of any non-`__block` variables it captures. Since `test1` is uninitialized at the time your block is created, you will be using an uninitialized pointer for `test1` when you run the block.

The proper solution is to declare `test1` with `__block`. That way, state is shared between the block and the enclosing scope, and after `test1` is assigned in the enclosing scope, the block can access the changed value:

```
__block TestClass *test1;
test1 = [[TestClass alloc] initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass %@", test1);
}];
[test1 exec];
[test1 release];
```

p.s. The 3rd example (doing `alloc` before and then assigning the result of `init`) is not reliable because in general an object's `init` method is not guaranteed to return the object it is called on (`init` is allowed to deallocate itself and return nil if it failed, for example).

---

**Update:** The above code is only for MRC, as `__block` variables are not retained by the block.

But in ARC, the above code will cause a retain cycle, as `__block` object pointer variables are by default retained by the block. In ARC, the correct code is:

```
TestClass *test1;
__block __weak TestClass *weakTest1;
weakTest1 = test1 = [[TestClass alloc] initWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"TestClass %@", weakTest1);
}];
[test1 exec];
```